# Spring Security using JBoss <security-domain>

Tags: spring, authentication, jboss, spring-security, ldap

i'm building an application using Spring Security with an Java based @Configuration. Our JBoss EAP 6 Server has a *security-domain* configured which is defined in the jboss-web.xml-File.

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC
    "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 4.2//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_4_2.dtd">
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>ldapcomponent</security-domain> 
</jboss-web>
```

Is there a way to use this *security-domain* within my Spring Security WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

**Spring Security Java Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.?????
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("my-required-role").and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss Authentication requires a

```
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider
```

which can be added by the Method:

```
auth.authenticationProvider(...);
```

In Addition to that a

```
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter
```

should be registered.

Comment: How do you set up a PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider that uses the JBoss security-domain?